# How to get current uploaded bytes in php?

Tags: php

How can I log and get the current bytes being uploaded from a html form to a PHP script? I want to later store the current progress in a session or log so that another AJAX script can retrieve it. Here is my current code to read the current bytes but It doesn't work.

```
$file_type = $_FILES['Filedata']['type'];
$file_name = $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
$file_size = $_FILES['Filedata']['size'];
$file_tmp = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];

 $filePointer = fopen($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'], "rb");
 $rr=0;

 if ($filePointer!=false){
 while (!feof($filePointer)){
     $fileData = fread($filePointer, 4096);
     $rr =$rr+strlen($fileData);
     // Process the contents of the uploaded file here...
     $_SESSION['fname']=$rr;
 }

fclose($filePointer);
}

move_uploaded_file ($file_tmp, "files/".$file_name);
```

Comment: Yet another reason why PHP5.4 will be **(is)** awesome. Here's an example of the new [file upload progress feature](http://chemicaloliver.net/programming/php-5-4-file-upload-progress-and-html5-progress-bars/). Wait, you mean you haven't been playing with the latest 5.4 release candidates? Oh man, they're **sweetness**.

Comment: Im unsure if my current host will install this for me. The highest I can set my PHP settings is php 5.3 Would I be able to still do this feature with 5.3?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I doubt any hosting companies would install 5.4 yet, nor should they as it's not officially ready for production use. It should be officially released in the next month or so. For now you'll have to hack together a solution from the answers below. They're pretty solid, though, so you should be fine. If you're on shared hosting, you may have some difficulty with the answers below. If you've got a virtual private server (vps) you shouldn't have a problem doing it (or getting your host to install the needed pecl extensions).

Comment: Yea I'm on a shared hosting at the moment which is why this is such an issue. I just want to show some progress when uploading in InternetExplorer, with Chrome/Firefox its really easy since AJAX.upload can handle progress uploaded on the client side. But with IE this method does not work.

Answer (score 4):

You can not access the uploaded bytes that way as the script doesnt get called till the file is already uploaded.

Your server needs to have APC, or similar pecl packages installed

http://devzone.zend.com/1812/using-apc-with-php/

Or by using the HTML5 file api

http://www.matlus.com/html5-file-upload-with-progress/

The HTML5 is better as you dont have to change anything on the php side just setup the scripts to receive the files, but would require that the user's browser support the HTML5 file api.

Comment: Well Im doing this for Internet Explorer. If this HTML5 upload api is compatible with I.E and if its okay to use it in a commercial service then that would be great.

Comment: Also my host does not allow APC to be installed.

Comment: Yea some hosts dont allow the APC and other pecl packages to be installed, that's why i also mentioned the HTML5 API. And i believe IE has some HTML5 api in 9, but might be limited, it will be more usable when they release version 10. Other then that you would need to use flash, java, or use server side perl CGI script as it does have certain functions that can do what's needed

Answer (score 3):

There is a PECL package: http://pecl.php.net/package/uploadprogress

Else check this:

- http://devpro.it/upload_progress/
- http://www.johnboy.com/php-upload-progress-bar/

You have to find the correct file in tmp folder and measure the size. This size must be shown on a page which is crawled via AJAX every some seconds. The problem is how to match the correct session and file. But it is not impossible...